# react-router-dom.js not found after upgrade

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, react-router-dom

Got a `Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` error in the browser after upgrading.
I have tried upgrading by modifying version in `package.json` and then `npm install --save react-router-dom`, also using command `npm install --save react-router-dom@6`
Both seems successful with result

```
+ react-router-dom@6.22.3 
updated 1 package and audited 3533 packages in 24.94s
```

But in runtime it is missing and also missing in `npm outdated`.

Does it have to do with the version of my other package? Here are some react related packages versions.

```
react                                    17.0.2   17.0.2        18.2.0  xpcms-laravel-react
react-data-table                          1.0.2    1.0.2         0.1.0  xpcms-laravel-react
react-data-table-component               6.11.8   6.11.8         7.6.2  xpcms-laravel-react
react-dom                                17.0.2   17.0.2        18.2.0  xpcms-laravel-react
react-i18next                           11.18.6  11.18.6        14.1.0  xpcms-laravel-react
react-notifications-component             3.4.1    3.4.1         4.0.1  xpcms-laravel-react
react-redux                               7.2.9    7.2.9         9.1.0  xpcms-laravel-react
react-scripts                             4.0.3    4.0.3         5.0.1  xpcms-laravel-react
reactstrap                               8.10.1   8.10.1         9.2.2  xpcms-laravel-react
redux                                     4.2.1    4.2.1         5.0.1  xpcms-laravel-react
redux-thunk                               2.4.2    2.4.2         3.1.0  xpcms-laravel-react
```

Extra info: the browser says it cannot find the react-router-dom in `node_modules\react-router-dom\esm\react-router-dom.js`, but the v6 is do not have that path, here is the v6 installed folder.

[image]

Is there a setting I am missing?

Extra info2:
I see there is no esm under v6 from here : `https://unpkg.com/browse/react-router-dom@5.2.0/esm/`.
What should I do to be able to use it again?

Answer (score 0):

Remove folder `node_modules` and run `npm install` to let it install every package again solves the issue

Only install the `react-router-dom` is not enough even though there are no error in installing the package